Asymptotical stability and stability for homogenous ODE
Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove, that the zero solution of $x'=Ax$ is

Asymptotically stable $\iff$ $Re(\lambda)<0$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of matrix A
Stable $\iff$ $Re(\lambda) \leq 0$ and if $Re(\lambda)=0$ then its Jordan block is of size 1.

Using that the matrix exponential $e^{tA}$ is the solution to the system and finding an orthonormal matrix $S$ and Jordan normal form matrix $B$, such that
$$A=SBS^{-1},$$ because of the properties of matrix exp. we get
$$e^{tA}=Se^{tB}S^{-1}$$
$$e^{tD}=diag(e^{tJ_1},\dots,e^{tJ_k}),$$
where $J_1,\dots,J_k$ are individual Jordan blocks of B.

Regarding asymptotical stability, we can see that the solution will be a linear combination of the functions $e^{t \lambda_1},\dots,e^{t \lambda_n}$. Therefore if the zero solution is asymptotically stable, then the eigenvalues must have a negative real part in order for the solutions to approach 0 for $t \rightarrow + \infty$ and vice versa for the other implication.

For eigenvalues with negative real part, we reach the same conclusion as in part 1. For eigenvalue $\lambda$ with real part equal to zero, we will get either $e^{\lambda t}=e^{0}=const.$ or $e^{\lambda t}=e^{ict}=cos(ct)+isin(ct)$. In both cases, the function is bounded.


I don't see how to finish the proof for $Re(\lambda)=0$ from here and argue that the Jordan block size must be 1.

Hint. If the Jordan block size of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is $n>1$, there will be solutions of the form $t^ke^{\lambda t}$ with $k=0,\ldots,n-1$.

And in that case the solution will approach $\infty$ for $t \rightarrow +\infty$ and therefore the solution is unstable, unless I'm mistaken?

Or it will oscillate with an amplitude that goes to $\infty$.
